# Excel changes Scaling of Footer and Header randomly

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a document with pictures in the footer and header. This document is a template and has to be used on multiple different computers. This works perfectly fine and **looks the same on most of the devices**.

However, on a small amount of computers, the pictures in the header are getting **scaled down** to **80% of their original size**, even tough the Excel Version is the same.

What could cause this?